# Why are this seams there?

Tags: modeling, topology

I have been modeling and then I've noticed that I had a strange seam going at a certain part of my mesh, quite weird, can't figure out what is causing this to happend.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks like you have N-gon face that cause this error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extend those vertical edge-loops all the way through those three bottom horizontally-aligned faces (the top of those three clearly being an n-gon, not sure of the two below it). This should go a long way toward fixing your problem.

Comment: Is there a way I can extend the loopcuts without using the knife tool?? as it is going to take ages with it.

Comment: You could use Ctrl+R on the bottom two faces, then roll the mouse wheel until you get the 9 or more cuts you need, then use Ctrl+E -> 'Edge Slide' on the edges to align them to existing edge loops above.